# Access shortcut for class property by operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i trying to implement "access shortcut" for class property by operator overloading, but i can't get it to work. Is it even possible ?

What i tried:

```
struct Fruit {
    float energy;
    float taste;
}

template<typename T>
class Value {
public:
    T val;
    T& operator->() { return val; }
}

Value<Fruit> apple;

// this work:
apple.val.energy = 0.5f;
cout << apple.val.energy << endl;

// this do not and i want this to work:
apple->energy = 0.5f;
cout << apple->energy << endl;
```

Comment: pretty sure `operator->` needs to return a pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `operator->` must return a pointer, but yours does not.  The compiler should have warned you about that, eg:

> error: result of ‘operator->()’ yields non-pointer result

Try this instead:

```
template<typename T>
class Value {
public:
    T val;
    T* operator->() { return &val; }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/AkbPKf)

Comment: Surely it must just return something that `operator->` can be applied to?

Comment: @Kazz: `operator->` can't just return *something*, it **MUST** return either 1) a pointer, or 2) another class with an overloaded `operator->`